# Adding a TMC2209 driver to BIGTREETECH SKR mini E3 V3.0 control board using Marlin

Tags: marlin, stepper-driver, bigtreetech, serial-connection, tmc2209

I haven't started on the hardware for this project yet as I'm still waiting for delivery, but I would just like to sense-check my current software mods and hardware plans to see if I'm along the right lines. I am going to take the BIGTREETECH SKR mini E3 V3.0 board and add a 5th stepper driver to get independent control of the Z axes on my printer. Having studied the [pins](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/blob/master/hardware/BTT%20SKR%20MINI%20E3%20V3.0/Hardware/BTT%20E3%20SKR%20MINI%20V3.0_PIN.pdf) on the board and the [schematics](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/blob/master/hardware/BTT%20SKR%20MINI%20E3%20V3.0/Hardware/BTT%20E3%20SKR%20MINI%20V3.0_SCH.pdf) of the various ICs, my plan is to connect the TMC2209 to some spare pins on the board.

Using the BIGTREETECH PCB version of the driver:

[image: Diagram of the BIGTREETECH SKR mini E3 PCB]

I plan to attach the enable pin to PD0 on the SKR, MS1, and MS2 to ground, UART Tx/Rx to the first PDN as detailed in the [manual](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-TMC2209-V1.2/blob/master/manual/TMC2209-V1.2-manual.pdf), VM to the power supply, GND to the power supply, A2/A1/B1/B2 to the motor, VDD to a 3.3V pin from the SPI 1 block of pins on the SKR, and GND to ground.

I think this makes sense as the driver runs in UART mode - it is set to 0x0 by tying MS1 and MS2 to ground - and my present understanding is that in UART mode the CLK, STP, and DIR pins are not needed. I am not 100% on that point so I could be wrong there. If I do need to add it then STP and DIR are easy, CLK would be a bit more challenging but I believe UART does not require a clock signal.

As far as software changes are concerned, the main additions are in `pins.h` of Marlin 2.1.x where I have added:

```
#define Z2_ENABLE_PIN                       PD0  
#define Z2_STEP_PIN                         PD2 // not needed in uart mode?  
#define Z2_DIR_PIN                          PD3 // not needed in uart mode?
```

And then to hijack some hardware serial pins:

```
#define X_HARDWARE_SERIAL  MSerial4 // original code
#define Y_HARDWARE_SERIAL  MSerial4 // original code
#define Z_HARDWARE_SERIAL  MSerial4 // original code
#define Z2_HARDWARE_SERIAL MSerial1 // my addition
#define E0_HARDWARE_SERIAL MSerial4 // original code
```

Here is where I have the most doubt, I'm assuming that `MSerial1` corresponds to the Rx1 and Tx1 pins in the EXP1 block on the board.

In summary, my main questions are: do I need the CLK, STP, and DIR pins (maybe just STP and DIR?), and does using `MSerial1` correspond to the Rx1 and Tx1 pins?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same idea on the same board, but I think to stay with the DIR/STEP mode first.
The CLK is useless for the DIR/STEP mode, then I suppose that it is useful for UART mode.
But this datasheet is very strange, often there is Rx and Tx UART close to STEP pin
[image: STM2209 wiring]

When I read the Bigtreetech documentation from your link, only one wire is used for the UART (Rx/Tx). This is strange, or it is to be compatible with other driver and the CLK is useless.

I never used the TMC2209 with the uart, only in STEP/DIR mode and directly drove with a Raspberry Pico.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.